# Executing a Progress Database Query (4GL) using JDBC or ODBC

Tags: java, jdbc, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

Is there any way to execute a Progress query (4GL) using JDBC or ODBC in a Java project?

I've connected to the database and have to query the database using Progress (4GL). But the JDBC / ODBC only supports SQL queries, so it gives a syntax error.

Open Edge Database Version: 11.3.2

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes i have. I've connected to the database but have to query the database using Progress (4GL) but the JDBC / ODBC only supports SQL queries, so it gives a syntax error.

Comment: JDBC/ODBC are SQL-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC/ODBC is SQL-only.

If you want a Progress style query, you need to make a Webspeed, WSA or REST connection and pass the query string to the server-side software to execute the query.

For a WSA / REST call, this'll require an appserver, with an attendant license. You may be able to get away with using Ganimede or Blue Diamond as a webspeed client if you're doing local dev work.